# How to find the GitLab project size by using API?

Tags: api, curl, repository, size, gitlab

I trying to find the size of the project by using GitLab API. I got some Idea about this in GitLab [document](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository). But it seems to get the particular branch file size. Also, I tried this but I faced below exception in my browser.

> {"message":"400 (Bad request) \"file_path\" not given"}

I do not know, how to use this below API to get the project size. By using this same API I got the above error.

`https://gitlab.company.com/api/v3/projects/<project_ID>/repository/files?private_token=GMecwr8umMN4wx5L`

Answer (score 0):

You've got this error because this end-point have two required parameters

> ```
> file_path (required) - Full path to new file. Ex. lib/class.rb
> ref (required) - The name of branch, tag or commit
> ```

**Anyway, getting files count with this end-point** is impossible because this is for

> ```
> CRUD for repository files
> Create, read, update and delete repository files using this API
> ```

So you can just make CRUD operations for **one specified file**.

---

**Listing files may be done with** https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#list-repository-tree